# How does the word order work in the second sentence?

Tags: word-order

How does the word order work in the second sentence? Why is the word "mal" in the second position instead of a verb?

> Niemand verlässt die Formation. Nicht mal dann, wenn einer von uns getötet wird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a truncated sentence.

The full version would be:

- "Nicht mal dann [verlässt jemand die Formation], wenn einer von uns...."

**"nicht mal dann"** is one element, a time element to be precise. It's pretty empty content-wise so it gets specified in the **"wenn"**-sentence later on.

But it constitutes position 1 as a whole, and then would come the verb, but in this case, the rest of the main sentence is simply missing.

Answer (score 0):

"Nicht mal dann" would be taken as one word and as the above comment mentions, the hidden phrase is [verlässt jemand die Formation]. So "verlässt", a verb, is in the second position and hence the word order fits.